# Parse a block of text containing square braced "tags" to produce a grouped 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, associative-array, text-parsing

I want to create grouped data in an array from the following string.

```
[car]Ford[/car]
[car]Dodge[/car]
[car]Chevrolet[/car]
[car]Corvette[/car]
[motorcycle]Yamaha[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Ducati[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Gilera[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Kawasaki[/motorcycle]
```

The result should be:

```
array(
    'car' => array(
        'Ford',
        'Dodge',
        'Chevrolet',
        'Corvette'
    ),
    'motorcycle' => array(
        'Yamaha',
        'Ducati',
        'Gilera',
        'Kawasaki'
    )
);
```

Comment: it's called "string processing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to convert the information in this string to an associative array.

split the string on the new line into an array using the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$str = "[car]Ford[/car]
[car]Dodge[/car]
[car]Chevrolet[/car]
[car]Corvette[/car]
[motorcycle]Yamaha[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Ducati[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Gilera[/motorcycle]
[motorcycle]Kawasaki[/motorcycle]";

$items = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
```

At this point each delimited item is now an array entry.

```
Array
(
    [0] => [car]Ford[/car]
    [1] => [car]Dodge[/car]
    [2] => [car]Chevrolet[/car]
    [3] => [car]Corvette[/car]
    [4] => [motorcycle]Yamaha[/motorcycle]
    [5] => [motorcycle]Ducati[/motorcycle]
    [6] => [motorcycle]Gilera[/motorcycle]
    [7] => [motorcycle]Kawasaki[/motorcycle]
)
```

Next, loop over the array and pull out the appropriate pieces needed to build the final associative array using the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function with a [regular expression](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php):

```
$finalArray = [];
foreach($items as $item)
{
    //Use preg_match to capture the pieces of the string we want using a regular expression.
    //The first capture will grab the text of the tag itself.
    //The second capture will grab the text between the opening and closing tag.
    //The resulting captures are placed into the matches array.
    preg_match("/\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[/", $item, $matches);

    //Build the final array structure.
    $finalArray[$matches[1]] = $matches[2]
}
```

The following is an example of what will be found in the matches array for a given iteration of the foreach loop.

```
Array
(
    [0] => [motorcycle]Gilera[
    [1] => motorcycle
    [2] => Gilera
)
```

Please note that I use the [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant to explode the initial string. This may not work if the string was pulled from a different operating system than the one you are running this code on. You may need to replace this with the actual end of line characters that is being used by the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match_all()` to grab all qualifying substrings. You can use array destructuring to access convenient variables to push data into the result array in their respective groups.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1LUWL))

```
$result = [];
preg_match_all('#\[([^]]+)]([^[]+)\[/\1]#', $str, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($m as [1 => $group, 2 => $result[$group][]]);
var_export($result);
```

While iterating, we don't need the fullstring match so the `0` element is never accessed.  `1` is the substring inside of the opening tag -- this will be used as the grouping key. `2` contains the text between the opening and closing tags -- this value will be pushed into the result's group via `$result[$group][]`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you create two separate arrays?

```
$cars = array("Ford", "Dodge", "Chevrolet", "Corvette");

$motorcycle = array("Yamaha", "Ducati", "Gilera", "Kawasaki");
```

You could also use an Associative array to do this.

```
$variable = array("Ford"=>"car", "Yamaha"=>"motorbike");
```

Comment: I mean. I want to explode the string into arrays.